# Brew install chromedriver not working?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, homebrew

I am using MacOS, when I tried to install chromedriver using homebrew

```
brew install chromedriver
```

I get:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "chromedriver" 
It was migrated from homebrew/core to caskroom/cask.
You can access it again by running:
brew tap caskroom/cask
```

I typed `brew tap caskroom/cask` but chromedriver is still not installed.
Can someone please help me on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Update: This answer has been outdated. Please [follow the answer from @Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54077291/26510), which is now the correct answer.

After tapping `caskroom/cask` by using `brew tap caskroom/cask`,
install chromedriver using `brew cask install chromedriver`.
You can see other commands using `brew cask help`.

Comment: Homebrew is wonderful to use but it's so hard to remember these beer related metaphors and intuitively realize what to do. What does tapping a caskroom / cask even mean in this context? Yes, they have a page explaining it but it's not _intuitive_

Comment: outdated, if you try to find the current answer, see the next @Chris answer

Comment: Sorry but I wish this answer will be deleted or at least edited and mention the right answer..

Comment: Please see my answer below for the proper method.

Answer (score 47):

Update: This answer has been outdated. Please follow the answer from [@Nick Predey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086506/brew-install-chromedriver-not-working/54077291#67374819)

You can install it by running:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask

brew cask install chromedriver
```

Comment: This is the current answer now.

Comment: You can also run `brew cask upgrade chromedriver` if you want to upgrade an existing installation to the latest version.

Comment: Calling brew cask upgrade is deprecated. Use `brew upgrade --cask chromedriver`

Comment: Please see my comment below for the most updated answer.

Comment: also brew cask install is deprecated, gotta use brew install --cask

Answer (score 24):

The previous answers using `brew cask` etc. did not work for me.

As of May 2021, the following worked for me using homebrew:

`brew install chromedriver`

Which is confirmed by:

```
==> Downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/90.0.4430.24/chromed
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Installing Cask chromedriver
==> Linking Binary 'chromedriver' to '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
  chromedriver was successfully installed!
```

Comment: Confirmed this still works as of February 2022.

Answer (score 1):

`brew tap homebrew/cask && brew  install --cask chromedriver`

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In case you get the following error:

```
Error: Cask chromedriver-beta exists in multiple taps:
  homebrew/cask-versions/chromedriver-beta
  caskroom/versions/chromedriver-beta
```

untap the other **cask**:

```
$ brew untap caskroom/versions
```

Then follow the @Chris' answer:

```
$ brew cask install chromedriver
```

Answer (score -1):

Copy the below command and execute to download the latest script

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

Install chromedriver using brew

```
brew cask install chromedriver
```

Be sure to checkout updates to [brewinstall](https://brewinstall.org/install-chromedriver-on-mac-with-brew) if the commands get changed in the feature.